# Model-view separation, Airplane simulator

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to achieve Model-view separation. My airplane is a class. While developing the application, can't I use the console as sort of viewer. Can I spawn the airplane on it's own thread, while the console makes references to the airplane object to retrieve/read it's current altitude. I am trying to make the airplane an Active object, as in Java's runnable interface. How do you achieve this in .NET?

Comment: When you say 'Model-view' separation, do you mean you don't want your view to depend on your model or you don't want your view AND model to know of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by model view separation you mean something like [this](http://thedigitallifestyle.com/cs/blogs/developer/archive/2007/02/26/model-view-separation.aspx), then it is definately possible.

The challenge I would see in using the console as the viewer technology would be replicating the standard application message loop that occurs in a typical windows project.

But other than that, definately possible. Is there any specific reason why you want to use the console as the viewer? I would just go the WPF route personally, so I am interested to see what your motivation for the console approach would be?

Comment: Just for simplicity sake. So I don't have to learn WPF just yet. I wanted to learn delegates and events and thought that an airplane could provide the notions of events surrounding the ascent and descent of it's flight path.